# Evaluate the integral using the substitution rule

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> The integral is $$\int_0^4 \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1+2t}} \,dt$$

I set $u = 1+2t$ and got that $du = 2 dt$, which makes $dt = du/2$. After this, I am confused as to what to do because $2t$ is still in the equation.

(Also, I'm not sure how to format the equation on here so I apologize if there is any confusion)

Comment: You started correctly, and you are aware of importance to have only $u$ after the substitution. Good! Now replace in your integral $2t$ by $u-1$ and you can continue

Comment: If $u=2t+1$ then $2t=u-1$ right? Replace it and it's done.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that $2t = u-1$ and you get
$$
\int \frac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{du}{2}
$$
which cleanly splits into 2 integrals

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Keep going.

Well, students forget that the sub they make can be manipulated. Let $u = 1 + 2t$, so then $2t = u -1.$ Now the integral is

$$ \int_1 ^9 \frac{u-1}{2\sqrt{u}} \ du $$

which is easy to do once you properly separate the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

An other aproach

$$I=\int_0^4\frac{1+2t-1}{\sqrt{1+2t}}dt=$$

$$\int_0^4\sqrt{1+2t}dt-\int_0^4\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+2t}}$$